# DOM4J XPath 2.0

Tags: xpath, saxon, dom4j

I've seen various posts that DOM4J only supports XPath 1.0. I have some utilities that use DOM4J that now are being asked to support some dynamic parameters that are using XPath 2.0 functionality. Is anyone aware of examples of how to extend DOM4J to support XPath 2.0? Possibly using SAXON with it (again any examples or documentation)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Saxon XPath engine against DOM4J document trees. If you want this capability "out of the box" you need a Saxon-PE or -EE license; but the source code is available if you want to build it yourself.

You can do it using either the JAXP XPath interface (just supply a DOM4J document node where JAXP asks for an `Object`), or use Saxon's s9api interface: create a `net.sf.saxon.s9api.DocumentBuilder` and call its `wrap()` method to wrap the DOM4J document as an `XdmNode`. The results of queries will come back as `XdmNode` objects; `XdmNode.getExternalNode()` will return the underlying DOM4J `Node`.

Answer (score 0):

Online example is in the Saxon repository, here https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/master/entry/latest9.7/samples/java/he/S9APIExamples.java#L970 for Saxon 9.7 HE as it is the latest version to support "only" XPath 2.0 while newer versions (9.8 and later) will support XPath 3.1.